# First <li> displaying incorrectly

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I making a simple menu for a page using a list. The font size of all element but first I defined as 40px, for example. And the first continues with its default size. Doing that, the first `<li>` shows a strange space in it's top. See the fiddle.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4uggcyro/2/)

It's desirable to make all elements in the same position. Where this space comes from?

CODE:

```css
.logo-letter-text {
  width: 1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Bebas Kai";
  font-weight: 400;
  color: rgba(246, 244, 229, 1.0);
}
.nav-menu {
  position: relative;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8%;
  background: rgba(18, 18, 18, 1.0);
}
.nav-menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 30px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);
}
.nav-menu ul li {
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 0, 255, 1.0);
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-right: 12px;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
.nav-menu ul li:nth-child(n+2) {
  color: rgba(86, 86, 86, 1.0);
}
.nav-menu ul li:hover {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);
}
.nav-menu ul li:nth-child(1) {
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 1.0);
  background: rgba(255, 102, 0, 1.0);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.nav-menu ul li:nth-child(n+2) {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<body class="bg-theme-main">
  <nav class="nav-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><span class="logo-letter-text">M </span><span class="logo-letter-text">B </span><span class="logo-letter-text">A </span>
      </li>
      <li><span>A</span>
      </li>
      <li><span>B</span>
      </li>
      <li><span>C</span>
      </li>
      <li><span>D</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: Use `vertical-align: top`

Comment: @Vucko Thanks for solution. I didn't know this property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `.nav-menu ul li {display: inline-block}`

Use `.nav-menu ul li {float: left;}`

See fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4uggcyro/4/

Or another solution would be to use `display: flex;`

```
.nav-menu ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

See fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4uggcyro/6/

Answer (score 2):

`inline-block` by default is `vertical-aligne`d `baseline`, and you are setting it to `middle` the first but  you need to set it to `top`

```css
.logo-letter-text {
  width: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Bebas Kai";
  font-weight: 400;
  color: rgba(246, 244, 229, 1.0);
}
.nav-menu {
  position: relative;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8%;
  background: rgba(18, 18, 18, 1.0);
}
.nav-menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 30px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);
}
.nav-menu ul li {
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 0, 255, 1.0);
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-right: 12px;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.nav-menu ul li:nth-child(n+2) {
  color: rgba(86, 86, 86, 1.0);
}
.nav-menu ul li:hover {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);
}
.nav-menu ul li:nth-child(1) {
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 1.0);
  background: rgba(255, 102, 0, 1.0);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.nav-menu ul li:nth-child(n+2) {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<body class="bg-theme-main">
  <nav class="nav-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><span class="logo-letter-text">M </span><span class="logo-letter-text">B </span><span class="logo-letter-text">A </span>
      </li>
      <li><span>A</span>
      </li>
      <li><span>B</span>
      </li>
      <li><span>C</span>
      </li>
      <li><span>D</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
```